# CURL requests between docker containers

Tags: php, docker, curl, docker-compose, microservices

## Background

I've inherited a codebase for a system. For reference this is a symfony project.
The eventual plan is to move to a microservices architecture. The microservice responds only to web requests and is using JSONAPI to transfer data.

I've separately developed a new microservice and on its own. It has tested and performed well. It is not feasible to take the old system offline, so the approach is to transition service by service depending on business and infrastructure needs/possibility.

There are two separate docker container sets, one for "the old system" and one for "the microservice" (and its future other services). Both have various containers including php74.

As I have two web facing containers, I've mapped them as follows:

- `"80:80"` "the old system"
- `"8080:80"` "the microservice".

These do not clash on web traffic.

The microservice does plenty, but notably it runs a "hello world, welcome to the API" style response to a index `GET` request (let's call it `microservice.test`).

Within "the old system", I've mapped to the new system (I have tried both of the following methods)

```yaml
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - microservice.test
```

as well as:

```yaml
    extra_hosts:
      - "microservice.test:127.0.0.1"
```

As discussed, `microservice.test` responds on my local machine.

If I log into "the old system" php74 container, I can `ping microservice.test` and this is successful.

If I run a unit test from "the old system" and use cURL to download the index request, I get a `null` response. Note: if I ping or curl `google.com` I get a response.

The next step is to use the provided microservices client... but the above debugging step shows the issue.

Effectively, when php attempts to access the domain `microservice.test` it cannot see it.

## Question

How can I ensure that a docker container can access:

- a domain hosted on a different docker container set (different docker-compose file)

Note:

- This must use web only traffic
- php container can ping the `microservice.test` domain successfully
- cURL fails to get a response the `microservice.test` domain
- cURL successfully gets a response from external urls, such as google

Thanks in advance.

### cURL Code snippet (as requested)

```php
// 1. Open cURL session
$ch = curl_init();

// 2. Set options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://microservice.test:8080/");
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// 3. Execute and save response
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// 4. Close cURL session
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
// dumps shows content with google, NULL with test
```

Comment: Can you show a simple code segment which makes to he curl request plus any status it returns.

Comment: Added a response to the question as requested